# How to define a Gtk application menu in the main glade file

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

How can i define a Gtk application menu as described [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html#id-1.2.3.7.8) but within the main glade file where the rest of the application is defined?

So to put it in a file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="test">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The glade file should be integrated in python using gi.repository but I think this should not make any difference.

Comment: I don't think Glade shows application menus yet. You need to open the main glade file and add the contents of <interface> there.

Comment: Does it have to be in a separate <interface> tag or in the same as the main window?

Comment: What version of glade are you using? I'm not totaly sure of having understood your question because over glade 3.18.3 (The current on Debian Jessie), there are both buttons: Application Window & Application Menu. The Application window does exactly the same code you posted!

Comment: I can't find an Application Menu button anywhere on glade 3.20.0.

Comment: @XTL there isn't. You have to manually create it. You can take a look at the XML for it at [HowDoI/ApplicationMenu](https://developer.gnome.org/ApplicationMenu/).